# MySQL MyISAM query still optimized when the first column is null

Tags: mysql, myisam

In MySQL offcial document for **[count](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count)**,there are descriptions as below:

> For MyISAM tables, COUNT(*) is optimized to return very quickly if the SELECT retrieves from one > table, no other columns are retrieved, and there is no WHERE clause. For example:
>
> mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM student;
>
> This optimization only applies to MyISAM tables, because an exact row count is stored for this >storage engine and can be accessed very quickly. COUNT(1) is only subject to the same >optimization if the first column is defined as NOT NULL.

I want to test it for myself, and make a test as below,I make a table called `system_user` and the first column is `type`,all the value of `type` is null,however when I use `SELECT COUNT(1)` and `SELECT COUNT(*)` to query, I found the time cost is nearly the same,even if tried for serval times.

**I am wonder why the first column is null and the optimization in `MyISAM` is still working?**

[image]

When I use **SQL_NO_CACHE**,the time cost is still nearly the same:
[image]

related table:

```
CREATE TABLE `system_user` (
  `type` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

related procdure to create massive data:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `test`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `add_user_batch`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `add_user_batch`(IN COUNT INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT;
    DECLARE t_name VARCHAR(8);
    DECLARE t_tag VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE t_age INT(2);
    DECLARE t_sql_template VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE t_sql TEXT;   
    DECLARE t_tag_mod_val INT DEFAULT(25);
    DECLARE t_commit_mod_val INT DEFAULT(100);
    
    DECLARE t_start_time DATETIME;
    DECLARE t_end_time DATETIME;    
    
    TRUNCATE TABLE `system_user`;
    
    SET t_start_time=NOW();
    SET t_sql_template = “INSERT INTO `system_user`(NAME, age, tag) VALUES“;
    SET t_sql = t_sql_template;
    SET i = 1;
    WHILE i <= COUNT
        DO
            SET t_age = FLOOR(1 + RAND() * 60);
            SET t_name = LEFT(UUID(), 8);
            IF MOD(i, t_tag_mod_val) = 0 THEN
                SET t_tag = “NULL“;
            ELSE
                SET t_tag = CONCAT(“'“,LEFT(UUID(), 8),“'“);
            END IF;
 
            SET t_sql = CONCAT(t_sql,“('“,t_name,“',“,t_age,“,“,t_tag,“)“);
            
            IF MOD(i,t_commit_mod_val) != 0 THEN
              SET t_sql = CONCAT(t_sql,“,“);
            ELSE
              SET t_sql = CONCAT(t_sql,“;“);
                   SET @insert_sql = t_sql;
                   PREPARE stmt FROM @insert_sql;
                   EXECUTE stmt;
                   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
                   COMMIT;
              SET t_sql=t_sql_template;
            END IF;
            SET i = i + 1;
        END WHILE;
        
        IF LENGTH(t_sql) > LENGTH(t_sql_template) THEN
                   SET t_sql=CONCAT(SUBSTRING(t_sql,1,LENGTH(t_sql)-1),';');
                   SET @insert_sql = t_sql;
                   PREPARE stmt FROM @insert_sql;
                   EXECUTE stmt;
                   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
                   COMMIT;
        END IF;
        SET t_end_time=NOW();
        SELECT CONCAT('insert data success,time cost ',TIMEDIFF(t_end_time,t_start_time)) AS finishedTag;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Why does your title say InnoDB when the question is about MyISAM? And MyISAM is mostly obsolete, why are you concerned with this?

Comment: @Barmar, thank you,it's a typo, I have updated it

Comment: Your query may be cached, use this way: `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(*) FROM system_user;`

Comment: Check what is `1` in this query: `SELECT 1 FROM system_user`  - I've doubts that it's `type` field

Comment: @num8er, you can see in the head of my post, `mysql` offical document said to use `COUNT(1)`

Comment: I'm pointing to check when we talk about 1 to check which field mysql means: `SELECT COUNT(1), 1 FROM system_user`  - maybe query optimizer user primary key as `1`

Comment: @num8er I have updated my question ,and the result of `SELECT COUNT(1), 1 FROM system_user` is `10000000,1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247211/discussion-between-lucumt-and-num8er).